# How to convert byte[] to String without getting outofmemory error in Android?

Tags: android, string, arrays, apache-commons

I have developed an android application which will consume a large data in a zipped format. i used to unzip it and when i parse the unzipped file it shows outofmemory error since the Heap size increased to 125MB. I am using apache commons.io to fetch byte[] b and i am giving String s =new String(b);I tried Stringbuilder but i cant get that logic in place. Is there any other way to safely convert byte[] to String in android?

Comment: Don't forgot you are dealing with the mobile.....

Answer (score 6):

There isn't a way to convert that much data at once (125MB) to a string. You're better off doing this in incremental steps in more mangeable chunks.

Comment: Ya how to divide the byte[] into chunks and collect it in a string?\

Comment: Well, usually a character is a byte, so just parse each byte for the resulting string. More information here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4850316/354247

Comment: If this answered your question, think about accepting it for the benefit of future users.